Logstash-Not able to parse nested json
Below is my nested json, not able to parse it as array fields or flatten json
{
    "traceId": "o0uyveRU/8BkjL+lbpDlnQ==",
    "spanId": "73rmqIRmo34=",
    "tags": [
        {
            "key": "otel.library.name",
            "vStr": "com.mdi.core.workmgmt.TypedConsumer"
        },
        {
            "key": "ta.work.receivedTime",
            "vType": "INT64",
            "vInt64": "1721628429423"
        },
        {
            "key": "internal.span.format",
            "vStr": "otlp"
        }
    ],
    "process": {
        "serviceName": "TRADE_SINGLETON",
        "tags": [
            {
                "key": "deployment.environment",
                "vStr": "PSR"
            },
            {
                "key": "telemetry.sdk.version",
                "vStr": "1.34.0"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Below filter i have used but not getting the flatten json out:

filter {      json    {       source => "message" target => "parsedMsg"   }
json    {       source => "[parsedMsg][process][tags]" target =>
"parsedContent"   }  }

